# tomcat 8.5 server stopps immediately after starting

Tags: tomcat, installation, webserver, tomcat8, thingworx

I am currently trying to run my thingworx application the tomcat8.5 server. 
But every time I try to start the tomcat server, it shuts down automatically a few seconds after.

I have looked through the log files but only found this which could possibly help:

```
13-Sep-2017 14:48:00.893 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\Thingworx\WEB-INF\extensions]
```

Comment: Please provide the full log for a failed start.

Answer (score 1):

The log that you provided is not good enough for the exact solution. But it looks like Thingworx license issue. Make sure

1. This java option is added <-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\Thingworx\WEB-INF\extensions>
2. You have a valid license at your Thingworx platform location. By default, it is in the root folder of the Installed drive. e.g C:\ThingworxPlatform\license.bin

If your issue is not resolved,  share the following:

1. Thingworx version
2. Thingworx log file (default location: C:\ThingworxStorage\logs)